# How to make daily Jenkins Jobs Summary Report send to mail in Table format

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I tried my best to search and make sure this is not duplicate questions. but didn't get any. so writing it now.

We have Daily Scheduled jobs which runs in night time for our application. so we have our support team who actually make sure all jobs went successfully every night. if not raise a ticket/concern.
Now, Support team checks all this Jobs by going to Jenkins.

We are now looking for option to make this monitoring automated by sending in mail to all stakeholders.
Being said that **I have 10 jobs which I want all those jobs listed in a table with Status of execution of last night and send to group of people.**

How can we achieve this? is there any **Jenkins Plugin** which can help us?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am not aware of any plugin available for the same. But you can workaround using Jenkins API to get the status of all the jobs status and create table.

Comment: Hi @SouravAtta, thanks for comment. we tried to make it via API. problem we had is, even if we try to run the APIs using another job in same jenkins, we still need to pass the login creds to those API request. 

as per our company compliance policy, this is not allowed. so is there way we can get the details from API without creds? 
if so, could you please share as an example?

Comment: Hi @SouravAtta. Apologies. didn't get you. How jenkins pipeline job report API is related to SonarQube User access. Could you please share and example?

Comment: Sorry. I mistook the question. I have to write the comment on some other stackoverflow question related to sonarqube but I wrongly commented here. Let me delete the previous comment. Both the questions are same so I got confused :P

Comment: For accessing Jenkins API also, you can use the token of the Jenkins user to execute those API's.

Comment: Thanks @SouravAtta. will try that option once.

Comment: Hi @SouravAtta, thanks for your notes. we tried this method. works fine too. but process policy restricted to use this method. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was not allowed to use  API in our Jenkins due to some security constraints.
so had to go with below solution.

(have added only stage which we need for getting job status. feel free to edit/update as you need)

```
stage('Get status of Jobs') {
  steps {
    script {
      env.mailText=""
      def mailText = "============================================= \n"

      //Add your all jobs name in a list.
      allDailyJobs = ['Prod/Daily-Jobs/dbBackups', 'Prod/Daily-Jobs/productImport']

      allDailyJobs.each() { jobName ->
        //Remove the path prefix to get only Job name (to mention in mail report)
        def regex = ~"^Prod/Daily-Jobs/"
        String just_job_name = jobName - regex

        // Get the Job Latest Details
        def job_number = getBuildNumber(jobName)
        def job_result = getBuildStatus(jobName)
        
        //echo is paragraph format with lines sepearators
        mailText = mailText + " Daily Job Name => ${just_job_name} \n"
        mailText = mailText + " Build number => ${job_number} \n"
        mailText = mailText + " Build Status => ${job_result} \n"
        mailText = mailText + " ============================================= \n\n"
      }
      env.mailText = mailText
    }
  }
}

// Get the Last Build Numnber for the job.
@NonCPS
def getBuildNumber(String jobName) {
  def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)
  return  job.getLastBuild().getNumber()
}

// Get the Status of the Job
@NonCPS
def getBuildStatus(String jobName) {
  def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)
  return  job.getLastBuild().getResult().toString()
}
```

This stage gives "env.mailText" value which has all jobs details you need. we can use this one to send in mail or chats or to any Hooks.

**Important point** : this would require script approval in Jenkins to execute the task. so please make sure you have right access for it.
(to avoid this happening again and again, use it without sandbox checkout)

this is how it looks in mail.
[image]